# List files with a specific name and copy to a directory

Tags: r, xml, loops

I have several XML files in the “`D:/`” directory and I want to transfer part of these files to another directory, for example, `D:/FILES_XML`

The `D:/` directory has the following files:

```
2019010112_20009726.xml
2019010113_20009725.xml
2019010208_20009734.xml
2019010210_20009741.xml
2019010210_20009742.xml
```

I list the directory as follows:

```
setwd ("D: /")
files <- list.files (pattern = ".xml")
```

Of these 5 files I want to transfer to the `D:/FILES_XML` directory just 2 files. However, due to an internal failure in the process, the names of these files are different, as I can only see part of the name (I only see what is after the underscore “_”). Therefore, the 2 files I want are described as follows for me:

```
20009741
20009742
```

So, how would I go about transferring the 2 files, knowing that I only have a part of their name?

Result I want in the directory `D:/FILES_XML`:

```
2019010210_20009741.xml
2019010210_20009742.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adjust the regex patern match:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "(_20009741|_20009742).xml")
```

Alternatively, with many files, use `paste` to collapse into single regex string:

```
f <- c(20009741, 20009742)
m <- paste0("(", paste(f, collapse="|"), ").xml")
files <- list.files(pattern = m)
```

Then use `file.copy` to copy files:

```
file.copy(paste0(getwd(), "/", files), paste0(getwd(), "/FILES_XML/", files),
          overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion allows me to work with a few files at once. For example, how would you go about working with 100 files at once instead of 2? Is it possible to create something like this?

Comment: You can create the regex match with `paste(..., collapse)` on many files. See update.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion helped me a lot, but due to an R error I can't work with large files (I'm working with almost 10,000). See the R message: "Error in list.files (pattern = concatenate): assertion 'tree-> num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634"

Comment: Certainly, you may have hit a limit. Try breaking in 1,000 splits and pass into regex match to copy accordingly.